# make file by socket.makefile on a selected directory, not current script directory

Tags: python, file, sockets, makefile, directory

The part in my code is :

```
    def upload_action(client):
    """
     uploads the requested file by socket to server

     receives: socket - client socket
     returns: nothing
    """
       file, filename = get_file_and_filename(client.makefile('r'))
       write_to_file(file, filename)
```

I want to make the file and save it on a selected directory, not on current script directory. Is it possible?

For example, I want to make the file on c:\heights\files.
I want the file to be created by client.makefile('r') in that directory.
 How?

Comment: What directory? I don't see any references to a directory.

Comment: added an example path now

Comment: If my answer answered your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

By default the working directory is from where the script was run.
All relative paths are relative to the working directory.
A file name is just a relative path pointing to files in that working directory.

If you need to write a file to an arbitrary directory, you need to provide an absolute path to your filename.

```
write_to_file("c:\\heights\\files\\"+file, filename)
```

If you are only working with the files inside that directory, you can change the working directory to it by:

```
import os
os.chdir("c:\\heights\\files")
```

and use your script as it is.